# Check if redis variable changed externally in nodejs

Tags: node.js, redis

I need to check whether a redis value has been changed by another process and return it's value if it has been changed and false if it hasn't.

I believe that the watch function may be designed for this but I am struggling to understand how to implement it as the watch always returns OK irrespective of whether the variable was changed or not.

Here's what I have now, but this always returns the variable even if not changed.

```
function changed(){
    client.watch("tally", function (err,reply) {
        if(reply=="OK") client.get("tally", function(err, reply) { console.log(reply);});
        else console.log('nochange');
    });
    var x = setTimeout(function(){ changed(); },1000);  
}

changed();
```

Comment: This probably won't help, but you can use the `MONITOR` command to subscribe to all commands sent to redis. If you wanted to write tests which included redis, this would be one approach to watching for changes. That said, you might need to do a little parsing, and it would be terrible for most production applications due to the loss of performance.

Answer (score 0):

Watch always returns OK; see http://redis.io/commands/watch – it is used only in combination with MULTI/EXEC (transactions) to check EXEC return value.

You can monitor/poll a Redis key value like this:

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();

var keytracker;
function changed() {

    client.get("tally", function(err, reply) {
        if (err)
            console.log('A Problem with Redis: ' + err);

        if (reply == keytracker) {
            console.log('nochange');
        } else {
            keytracker = reply;
            console.log(reply);
        }
    });

    setTimeout(function() { changed(); }, 1000);
}

changed();
```